# Reactive site does not work with IE

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

I have been building a [personal website](http://konecny.dyndns.biz) using the [skeleton reactive page model](http://getskeleton.com). I had been using Chrome to test the site as it was my main browser. Everything works well in Chrome, however, yesterday I opened it up in IE 8 and IE 9 for the first time and the site looks awful but more importantly has lost the reactive functionality with the exception of the footer.

I've been pulling my hair out the past few days trying to figure out why IE refuses to dynamically size the page trying use the footer div on other parts of the page. Can anyone point to what is causing the problem or how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by reactive? Also, could you post some (relevant) code so we can see where the problem lies?

Comment: Also, your site looks just fine in my IE9, including when I have compatibility mode on..

Comment: Btw, why you content has incorrectly closed `p` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's said in [documentation](http://getskeleton.com/#support):

> There is a small hiccup though - older non-CSS3 browsers aren't going
>   to respond to the media-queries and thus will be served the standard
>   960 grid even if they are resized.

And yes, IE8 can be considered an 'older non-CSS3' browser.

Comment: I didn't realize that IE8 fell into that. Is IE9 considered a non-CSS3 browser as well?

Comment: At least IE9 supports CSS3 media-queries (even not without some quirks).